# Why has the number of medication errors increased by 463% between 2010 and 2016 in the US?

Tags: medications, united-states, public-health

https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation-now/2017/05/10/skin-melts-off-medication-error/315930001/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170511010443/https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation-now/2017/05/10/skin-melts-off-medication-error/315930001/))  says:

> According to the Food and Drug Administration, medication errors jumped from 16,689 in 2010 to more than 93,930 in 2016. That's nearly a 463% increase.

Why has the number of medication errors increased by 463% between 2010 and 2016 in the US?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USA Today article you linked to provides two potential explanations:

> The FDA said the spike is because of improvements made to its reporting system over the last two years. Pharmacy industry experts believe the numbers also reflect more people are filling more prescriptions than ever.

The first explanation seems quite plausible, as it's unlikely that the error rate would increase organically that fast in six years.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree with this - Higher reporting proportions will lead to higher overall numbers; A higher number of overall prescription fillings would also make sense. What I'd be worried about would be if the **rate** of filling errors went up 465%.

Comment: Good catch! I agree it's unsurprising such a growth be artificial. Follow-up question: [To what extent does filling more prescriptions increase the number of medication errors?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/12292/43)